# c# Nhibernate a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Estou a um tempo com esse erro e não consigo encontrar uma boa solução.

A gravação dos objetos funciona normalmente, porém para alterações ele me retorna esta mensagem:

> Additional information: a different object with the same identifier
>   value was already associated with the session

**Classe que retorna a session**

```
public class DataAccesLayer {
    private static DataAccesLayer _instance;
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    private DataAccesLayer() {
    }

    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private ISessionFactory SessionFactory {
        get {
            return _sessionFactory ?? (_sessionFactory = BuildFactory());
        }
    }

    public static DataAccesLayer Instance {
        get {
            return _instance ?? (_instance = new DataAccesLayer());
        }
    }

    private ISessionFactory BuildFactory() {
        try {
            IPersistenceConfigurer configDB = PostgreSQLConfiguration
                    .PostgreSQL82
                    .ConnectionString(ConnectionString)
                    .ShowSql()
                    .FormatSql()
                    .UseReflectionOptimizer();

            FluentConfiguration FConf = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(configDB)
                .Mappings(c => c.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<System.Retaguarda.Map.UsuarioMap>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true));

            return FConf.BuildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro ao carregar configurações do banco de dados\nDica: Verifique as configurações de conexão\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public ISession OpenSession() {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

**Método Gravar**

```
    ISession session = DataAccesLayer.Instance.OpenSession();

    public void Gravar(T entidade) {
        using (ITransaction transacao = session.BeginTransaction()) {
            try {
                session.SaveOrUpdate(entidade);
                transacao.Commit();
                session.Flush();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (!transacao.WasCommitted) {
                    transacao.Rollback();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Erro ao gravar:\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Se utilizar `session.Merge(entidade);` ele grava normalmente as alterações, porém da problema ao inserir novos itens. Pensei em uma possível solução, mas ficou meio estranho e não pretendo utilizar:

```
    try {
        session.SaveOrUpdate(entidade);
    } catch (Exception) {
        session.Merge(entidade);
    }
```

Outra possibilidade que testei foi executando um `session.Clear();` antes do `SaveOrUpdate`, porém ao tentar gravar um objeto "Pessoa" com lista de "Endereco" retorna outro erro:

> Additional information: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with
>   two open sessions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note que o `SaveOrUpdate()` só deve ser utilizado sob uma destas circunstâncias:

- O objeto (entidade) é novo - ou seja, chave-primária está vazia (zerada, nula, etc) e deverá ser gerada; Equivale a chamar o método `Save()`;
- O objeto (entidade) possui uma chave que já existe **no banco de dados**, porém ainda não foi carregado pela `ISession`. Equivale a chamar o método `Update()`;

O método `Merge()` faz o mesmo procedimento acima, adicionando o seguinte comportamento:

- Se a entidade possui alguma chave-primária válida, lê o registro para verificar se o mesmo existe no banco (equivalente `Get()`). Se já existir, copia os dados da entidade atualizada para a entidade recém-carregado do banco. Se não existir, considera `Save()`;

Se, contudo, uma entidade já está carregada no cache da sessão (via método `Get()` ou *lazy-load*, por exemplo), qualquer um dos métodos acima irá falhar.

Quando uma entidade já está carregada na `ISession`, não é necessário chamar nenhum método para efetivar a alteração. Isto porque o NHibernate é um framework que possui rastreamento de alterações (*change-tracking*) nativo.

No seu caso, a atualização deve ser resumida simplesmente assim:

```
// só isto basta - note que isto irá atualizar (UPDATE) 
// todas as entidades cujas propriedades foram alteradas
session.Flush();
```

Comment: Interessante a explicação, faz todo sentido. Mas desta forma ele está alterando apenas na session, enquanto estou com ela aberta (não grava no banco de dados). O que eu poderia estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: O `session.Flush()` deveria por si só disparar o(s) `UPDATE`(s) e quaisquer outros comandos de alteração de dados no banco. Outra forma seria usar a `ISession` dentro de um bloco `using` (semelhante como vc fez com a transação), que é o recomendado pelo conceito que o NHibernate se baseia (*unit-of-work pattern*), disparando todas as alterações realizadas no banco de dados ao fim do `using`.

Comment: Só um outro detalhe. Como o NHibernate observa suas entidades (uma vez que elas foram carregadas), ele só irá disparar um `UPDATE` caso uma (ao menos) propriedade tenha sido alterada. Entidades que não foram alteradas não geram qualquer comando DML ao `Flush()`.

Comment: Então, nas pesquisas encontrei alguma coisa neste sentido:
 `O objeto SessionFactory, este sim deve ser criado apenas uma vez e único por banco de dados. (SessionFactory = singleton)`

 `O objeto Session tem um custo muito pequeno de criação, e deve ser criado / destruído a cada ciclo (OpenSession())`.

Desta forma tenho uma session para cada transação: `using (ISession session = DataAccesLayer.Instance.OpenSession()) {...}`

Comment: Nesse caso o: `session.SaveOrUpdate(entidade);` funciona perfeitamente, para todos os objetos. Mas ao tentar carregar o objeto pessoa com uma lista de endereços, ele traz apenas a pessoa e da erro ao tentar acessar o endereço:
`-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Pessoa.Enderecos, no session or session was closed`
Ai percebi que se eu utilizar .Not.LazyLoad() no atributo Enderecos dentro do PessoaMap, carrega normal. Estaria correto utilizar desta forma, ou perderia muito em desempenho?